# rake aborted! no such file to load -- devise/schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, rake

I have been running this app for month with no issues. but now I keep getting this error when I run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I have tried the basics fixes, removing/install the gem, destroy the app and redeploy. bundle install on Heroku.

here is my gem file

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.1)
actionpack (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.1)
activeadmin (0.4.3, 0.4.2)
activemodel (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.1)
activerecord (3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.1)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.2)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.2.2)
activeresource (3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.1)
activesupport (3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.3, 3.1.1)
acts_as_indexed (0.7.8)
addressable (2.2.7, 2.2.6)
ansi (1.4.2, 1.4.1)
arel (3.0.2, 3.0.0, 2.2.3, 2.2.1)
awesome_nested_set (2.1.3)
babosa (0.3.7)
backbone-on-rails (0.9.1.0)
backup (3.0.23)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bootstrap-sass (2.0.1)
bourbon (1.4.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21 ruby)
capybara (1.1.2)
childprocess (0.3.1)
chronic (0.6.7)
chunky_png (1.2.5)
client_side_validations (3.1.3)
cocaine (0.2.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.3)
commonjs (0.2.5)
compass (0.11.7)
copycopter_client (2.0.0)
daemon_controller (1.0.0, 0.2.6)
daemons (1.1.8)
devise (2.0.4, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.5.2)
devise_invitable (1.0.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
dragonfly (0.9.12)
dynamic_form (1.1.4)
eco (1.0.0)
eco-source (1.1.0.rc.1)
ejs (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
execjs (1.3.0, 1.2.13, 1.2.12, 1.2.9)
factory_girl (2.6.0)
factory_girl_rails (1.7.0)
faker (1.0.1)
faraday (0.7.5)
fastercsv (1.5.4)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.11)
flutie (1.3.3)
foreman (0.40.0)
formtastic (2.1.0, 2.0.2)
friendly_id (4.0.4)
fssm (0.2.8.1)
globalize3 (0.2.0)
gon (2.2.2)
guard (1.0.1)
guard-rspec (0.7.0)
haml (3.1.4)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
haml_rails (0.1.0)
has_scope (0.5.1)
hashie (1.2.0)
heroku (2.16.2)
hike (1.2.1)
hpricot (0.8.6, 0.8.5)
htmldiff (0.0.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
inherited_resources (1.3.1, 1.3.0)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2)
journey (1.0.3, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
jquery-rails (2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.0.19)
json (1.6.6, 1.6.5, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2)
json_pure (1.6.5)
kaminari (0.13.0)
launchy (2.0.5)
less (2.1.0, 2.0.11)
less-rails (2.2.0, 2.1.8)
letter_opener (0.0.2)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-linux)
mail (2.4.4, 2.4.1, 2.3.3, 2.3.0)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.18, 1.17.2)
minitest (2.11.1)
multi_json (1.3.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.4)
multipart-post (1.1.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
newrelic_rpm (3.3.2)
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
oauth (0.4.5)
oauth2 (0.5.1)
omniauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-facebook (1.1.0)
omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.8)
omniauth-identity (1.0.0)
omniauth-linkedin (0.0.6)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
omniauth-twitter (0.0.7)
open4 (1.3.0)
orm_adapter (0.0.7, 0.0.6, 0.0.5)
paper_trail (2.6.3)
paperclip (2.7.0)
passenger (3.0.11)
pg (0.13.2)
pjax_rails (0.1.10)
Platform (0.4.0)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
POpen4 (0.1.4)
popen4 (0.1.2)
rack (1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.3.6, 1.3.5)
rack-cache (1.2, 1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-pjax (0.5.5)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.1)
railties (3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.1)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rake-compiler (0.7.9)
rdoc (3.12, 3.11)
redcarpet (2.1.1)
refinerycms (2.0.3)
refinerycms-authentication (2.0.3)
refinerycms-core (2.0.3)
refinerycms-dashboard (2.0.3)
refinerycms-images (2.0.3)
refinerycms-pages (2.0.3)
refinerycms-resources (2.0.3)
responders (0.9.1, 0.6.5)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.8.0)
rspec-core (2.8.0)
rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
rspec-rails (2.8.1)
ruby_parser (2.3.1)
rubyXL (1.2.5)
rubyzip (0.9.6.1, 0.9.5)
sass (3.1.15, 3.1.12, 3.1.11)
sass-rails (3.2.5, 3.2.4, 3.2.3, 3.1.5)
selenium-webdriver (2.13.0)
seo_meta (1.3.0)
sexp_processor (3.2.0)
simple_form (2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.5.2)
spork (0.9.0)
sprockets (2.1.2, 2.0.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.5, 1.3.4)
squeel (0.9.5)
ssl_requirement (0.1.0)
stringex (1.3.2)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
test-loop (13.0.1)
therubyracer (0.10.0, 0.9.10, 0.9.9)
thin (1.3.1)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
truncate_html (0.5.4)
turn (0.9.4, 0.9.1, 0.8.3)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.4)
tzinfo (0.3.33, 0.3.32, 0.3.31)
uglifier (1.2.4, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0)
warden (1.1.1, 1.1.0)
watchr (0.7)
whenever (0.7.3)
will_paginate (3.0.3)
xpath (0.1.4)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

Not sure what else might help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had upgraded to devise 2.0 by using bundle upgrade, but not run rails g install:devise after the upgrade, after I did that on my local machine I added the following to my .gitignore file, so this wouldn't happen again

- db/schema.rb
- vendor/*

destroyed my app on heroku and started a new one. Thank goodness I backup everything, just pointed everything back at the new app and it worked just like the old.